# next.js tailwindcss not loading style

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have next.js with tailwind CSS installed. I configured everything accordingly to the instructions. All codes are below.

**_app.js**

```
import '../styles/index.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: ["tailwindcss"],
}
```

**index.js**

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      
    </div>
  )
}
```

**index.css**

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

When I look up on index.css for any changes from browser (I use chrome) it stays the same. I'm not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Please Provide all code, maybe index.js from pages folder ?

Comment: Added index.js file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure that You installed `tailwindcss` with `next.js` properly.
Here you have reference to [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs)

---

Then Just use it, example **index.js** page.

```
import Head from "next/head";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <div className="flex items-center justify-center h-screen flex-col gap-5">
        <h1 className="text-3xl text-red-500 font-semibold">Tailwind CSS</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: I installed everything correctly.

Comment: @QI10 So try my code in action and everything should work as it should ;-) Good Luck! Best Regards!

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: Found the issue, it was related with tailwind.config.js. Thanks!

Comment: You 're Welcome Best regards !

Answer (score 0):

on tailwind.config.js make sure that in content include the extensions

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```